# Java 11 SE console output

Tags: java, cmd, console, output, executable-jar

Before Java SE, a a java application would auto-magically output the System.out stream to the console (CMD for windows, etc.) simply by running `java -jar yourprogram.jar`.

However now with Java SE, the libraries and run-time environment are packaged all together into one jar file so you don't have to worry about having the latest version of java installed on your computer.

That's great and all but now you cannot start the jar file with the said command above as it will try to run with the latest JRE which is 1.8. This will cause it to fail with the error `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError`. I am currently using SE 11 for my project (much newer). If I run the java executable in CMD with just `yourprogram.jar`, it does run, but without any console output.

I've been googling this for an hour now but with no luck. How exactly do I create a Java SE jar that will output to CMD (or any console)?

EDIT: Fixed old command syntax

Comment: The command has never been `java -jre yourprogram.jar` - I assume you mean `java -jar yourprogram.jar`, and you should not be getting such an error. Unless you are trying to run code compiled by Java 11 (with default settings) on Java 8; you need to specify the `-source` and `-target` to `javac` if you wish to do that.

Comment: This is not "before Java SE" and "after Java SE".  Java SE refers to the entire platform, and this term has been used since Java 1.2; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition

Comment: Fixed command lol and sorry for confusion. I meant Java 1.8 vs Java 11 essentially.

Answer (score 1):

Your global Java command has most likely been installed at one time or another to provide Java for browsers (which also installs a globally available Java command).

Recent versions of Java (I have primarily looked at OpenJDK) do not do this, so the global Java command keeps being the old one giving the errors you see.

The easiest fix is to put the `bin` folder of your installation at the front of the PATH variable, so new CMD's see and use `java` from there first.